# hadoop architecture query example

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Currently i have 2 machines one of them is the Horton sandbox i have configured it as name node and decommissioned the data node from it and other machine which i have made and made it as a data node and i have installed hive server on it.
Also and assigned the slave role to it and i used Ambari to finish it .
My question is as its my first time ever to use hadoop my plan is to transfer data from sql database to the hadoop so does this mean i have to install mysql on datanode while i will be using sqoop and other thing what will the name node do ?shall i query it and it passes the queries to the datanode am really very much confused and really having huge pressure to finish so forgive me as am newbie the installations of the machines are all default i have chosen datanode for the First machine and nodemanager for the second one with no special configurations appreciate if You have a simple example from which i can understand .
Thanks alot fellows

Answer (score 0):

**Sqoop** is a tool designed to transfer data between Hadoop and relational database servers. It is used to import data from relational databases such as MySQL, Oracle to Hadoop HDFS, and export from Hadoop file system to relational databases.

example like- you have some data in mysql in other machine and you have to transfer the data into your hadoop hdfs. In this condition sqoop will be used

**NameNode** stores MetaData(No of Blocks, On Which Rack which DataNode the data is stored and other details) about the data being stored in **DataNodes** whereas the DataNode stores the actual Data.

Comment: this meand that when you run query you are querying the datanode and does this require to install mysql on the datanode and what sort of information should i get from namenode as i will be transferring data to the datanode in order to complete my graduation project